# convert json data to pandas dataframe in python (dictionary inside list )

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json data like below:

```
{"name": "Monkey", "image": "https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2017/09/12/macaca_nigra_self-portrait-3e0070aa19a7fe36e802253048411a38f14a79f8-s800-c85.webp", "attributes": [{"trait_type": "Bones", "value": "Zombie"}, {"trait_type": "Clothes", "value": "Striped"}, {"trait_type": "Mouth", "value": "Bubblegum"}, {"trait_type": "Eyes", "value": "Black Sunglasses"}, {"trait_type": "Hat", "value": "Sushi"}, {"trait_type": "Background", "value": "Purple"}]}
```

I want to convert this json data as pandas dataframe only selecting the attributes as filter it as below:

```
Bones   Clothes    Mouth      Eyes    Hat      Background
zombie   striped    bubblegum  black   sushi    purple
```

Can any expert please help me to get the output as i mentioned
Thank you

Comment: Denote your original dictionary by orig, then: df = pd.DataFrame({att['trait_type']: [att['value']] for att in orig['attributes']})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a prettier solution but this does the job:

```
import json 
import pandas as pd

with open('file.json') as f:
    trait_types= []
    values = []
    data = json.load(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    for key in data['attributes']:
        trait_types.append(key['trait_type'])
        values.append(key['value'])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'trait type': trait_types,
    'value' : values})
print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you code is correct but only issue now is that i want the "trait type" values to be columns headers and "value" values to be the data.can you make that happen

Comment: Use dict(zip(trait_types,values) to convert the two lists into one dictionary. Then use pd.Dataframe.from_dict to put it into your layout